# tkinter child program not closed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 `tkinter` programs. The main program will have button to open the second program. The problem is when I try to close the child program, the main program is closed instead. I close the second program with command `app.destroy()`.

How to fix this?

The programs have this script

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import os

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self, background="black")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageCheck, PageUpdate, PageDigital, PageAnalog,
                  PageResult, PageHasil):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            ##self.overrideredirect(1)

            self.geometry("800x480")
            self.title("IC Checker")
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

##frame class

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should there be more code than this? Also when you child program, do you mean really child window?

Comment: What is "the child program"? I only see one program here.

Comment: @BryanOakley I guess he is referring to the second window that is opened by clicking the button in the first one...

Comment: Please, show us all the code you are working on, otherwise it is difficult for us to guess what is the problem...

Comment: @ChristopherWallace: I don't see a button, either. There's nothing to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use withdraw() to 'destroy' it, and deiconify or iconify to show it again if u want.WITHDRAW have to bw written in your childapp.protocol("WM_DELETEWINDOW",somefunction) in somefunction just use withdraw on  child app